# send integer parameters to a process in C#

Tags: c#, integer, arguments

i'm going to launch multiple programs .i need to send them some arguments.i have googled a lot about this but i just found something about sending String argument.how can i Send Integer?
for example :

```
int X=100;
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "X";
```

but it just send X not the value of X.

Comment: You might want to go back to the basics before you try running processes.

Comment: it was just a misunderstanding,i was just following the structure.i thought it can send parameters to the other side like other normal ways.for example when you call a function you can use:MyFunc(x)
i was thinking that it is calling like that one.i wanted to force in using that structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes.

```
int X = 100;
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = X.ToString();
```

If you put quotes around something, it will be treated as a string even if it is a variable enclosed within double quotes.

To use variable values, you need to refer to the variable just by the name.

Arguments are always passed as strings. It is the application using the arguments which is responsible for correctly parsing it as the correct value (e.g. - integer, double, boolean, etc.).

Comment: myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments just want string value.

Comment: Anyway the value you will get on the other side will always be a string, and you'll have to perform a conversion to get your integer value back.